# cannot find -lgsl when i trying to use arm-linux-gcc

Tags: lubuntu, compiling

Hallo I'm new in Ubuntu.

I'm now using Lubuntu 15.04. arm-linux-gcc and gsl has been installed and I can use gcc to compile exe file with gsl. But when I trying to use arm-linux-gcc to compile exe files I got a error

> "/usr/local/arm/4.3.2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgsl"

This is the code I used for cross compiling.

```
 $ arm-linux-gcc -o fft_test fft_test.c -L/home/peter/gsl/lib -I/home/peter/gsl/include -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

Comment: Did you already install appropriate arm versions of gsl and blas into /home/peter/gsl? If so, how exactly?

Comment: Thank you.Yes. I do following a youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrvnJaj7Ogk. But  I can only compile this source code with gcc compiler.

Comment: Could you please specify which ARM platform and distro on that platfrom you are using? Cross-compilation is very depend on such info, because even if you build your app on your PC it couldn't run on your ARM device due to ABI incompatibility used in ARM distro.

Comment: Thank you. I use arm7. which compiler I can use for this platform?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you didn't install libgsl in your system since path `/home/peter/gsl` is not a path where Ubuntu installs binaries. I can only suppose you have only downloaded sources of libgls from GNU server and did unpack them to `/home/peter/gsl`. This isn't a canonical way. You don't need to download libgsl manually, because Ubuntu already delivers thousands of libraries and tools in packages from its online repositories. To manage packages (download, install, and remove), you should use the `apt-get` tool.

**UPD:** As suggested in comments, you are trying to cross-compile your application to run on ARM platform. This requires some additional steps. I suppose that Linux distro installed on your ARM device is 32bit and is using armhf/hard-float ABI (*btw, official Ubuntu doesn't provide soft-float binaries*).

Add new architectures and online repositories to your Ubuntu:

```
REL=$(lsb_release -sc)
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf

sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ ${REL} main universe multiverse restricted"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ ${REL}-updates main universe multiverse restricted"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ ${REL}-security main universe multiverse restricted"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ ${REL}-restricted main universe multiverse restricted"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ ${REL}-backports main universe multiverse restricted"

sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can install tools for cross-compilation and ARM version of libgsl:

```
sudo apt-get install crossbuild-essential-armhf libgsl0-dev:armhf
```

Now you can try to compile your app:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o fft_test fft_test.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

There are no `-L` parameters as all libgsl files are now reachable by the compiler from system folders.

Comment: Won't that just install the *native* versions of the libraries?

Comment: thank you. I use ./config --prefix= to change the path of install, because under default install it said "usr/local/include/gsl" is not safe...                           I also installed the libgsl0-dev.                                                                                      The problem is I can use "gcc -o fft_test fft_test.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm".

Comment: sometimes I think maybe gsl can not be cross compile by arm-linux-gcc or I need do someting more?

Comment: The error is "/usr/local/arm/4.3.2/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: library search path "/usr/local/lib" is unsafe for cross-compilation"

Comment: @steeldriver Good point. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thak you that solved my problem I needed to install jsoncpp for arm on my laptop and used sudo apt-get install crossbuild-essential-armhf libjsoncpp-dev:armhf